# Redshift Connections not closed in proper way

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-redshift, connectivity

I'm working with redshift with both Java and Node Js. Few time ago found that disconnect event not created on all close connection calls.
Java (using *redshift.jdbc41* ):

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
       ...
} catch (Exception ex){
    throw new Exception("Can't sync raw data from redshift");
}finally {
    try {
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and Node Js (using *pg* module) example:

```
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    client.query(query, function (err, result) {
        client.end(function (err) {if (err) throw err;});
        ...
    });
});
```

So after executing query called code to close connection, but in *stl_connection_log* for part of connections created only *initiating session* event, but no *disconnecting session*, so lots of connections holds as active for days, and not resets after client application was stopped.

can somebody advice how to solve this issue? May be required some configs for redshift or another way of working in client application?

Comment: You can set idleTimeoutMillis: in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The Node Js code you mentioned works fine for me. If you want to close the connection forcefully through redshift, you can use below query.

```
select pg_terminate_backend (pg_backend_pid());
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.